# new link in print menu highcharts

Tags: highcharts

There are 10 graphics on one page. I want to display the data on these pages in the new page.I made export-csv.js insert. I made the addition;

`$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('gool', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        id: '101',
        text: 'Soccer Gool'`

` Highcharts.Chart.prototype.downloadItem = function () {

```
    var url = this.title.textStr.replace(/ /g, '-').toLowerCase();
    var url = this.title.id;

    var left = (screen.width/2)-(750/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(600/2);
    return window.open('itemExport.jsp?Id='+url+asd, 'Export', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+900+', height='+600+', top='+top+', left='+left);

};

// Add "Download CSV" to the exporting menu. Use download attribute if supported, else
// run a simple PHP script that returns a file. The source code for the PHP script can be viewed at
// https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/studies/csv-export/csv.php
if (Highcharts.getOptions().exporting) {
    Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
        textKey: 'downloadCSV',
        onclick: function () { this.downloadCSV(); }
    }, {
        textKey: 'downloadXLS',
        onclick: function () { this.downloadXLS(); }
    },{
        textKey: 'downloadItem',
        onclick: function () { this.downloadItem(); }
    });
}
```

`
I can not get the id variable.What should I do for the code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a custom property for an element then you access it via `chart.options`. In your case it would be `this.options.title.id`.